# Creating a content type without inheritance

Tags: content-type, site-column

I want to create a simple two column content type. I don't want to inherit any columns form a parent but I can't seem to make one without having to specifying a content type to inherit from.

Thanks

Comment: SharePoint is not a database, everything is (derived from) Item, with an ID and a Title. You can hide those fields, you can't delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it but you could try inherit from the System content type (0x), so your CTID would be e.g., 0x00, or even 0x02 (as 0x01 is reserved for the build-in Item).